# wlan0 stays down

Tags: kali-linux, wlan

whenever I try to connect to connect to wlan0 it says it is down but whenever I try to put it up by using the command `ifconfig wlan0 up` then I try `ip address`but it still doesn't come up

```
     ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:d4:02:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:6a:dd:a1:fc:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:c0:ca:99:3e:3b
```

how do i fix this this is kali vm kali is the only Linux flavour that does this this is a alfa adaptor called Alfa Network AWUS036NHA – USB WIFI Adapter, 150 Mbps, 802.11b/g/n, RP-SMA, AR9271L Atheros Chipset

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be having wlan0 interface. But you have **wlx00c0ca993e3b** interface.

so try

```
ifconfig wlx00c0ca993e3b up
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, you don't have a `wlan0`. If you want a `wlan0`, for example because a number of scripts depend on it, you can rename your network device:

```
/sbin/ip link set wlx00c0ca993e3b down
/sbin/ip link set wlx00c0ca993e3b name wlan0
/sbin/ip link set wlan0 up
```

after that, `ifconfig wlan0 up` should work.

Comment: the commands don't work I get wlx00c0ca993e3b: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device the issue only effects kali VMs and my alfa adaptor model is Alfa Network AWUS036NHA – USB WIFI Adapter, 150 Mbps, 802.11b/g/n, RP-SMA, AR9271L Atheros Chipset

Comment: You have changed the name of the interface in your question from `wlx00c0ca993e3b` to `wlan0`. The fact that there was an inconsistency between the names in the `ip address` and the `ifconfig wlan0 up` was the most obvious error.  And, if indeed the name is now `wlan0`, the commands that I gave you will clearly not work, because, as I explained, these commands rename the network interface `wlx00c0ca993e3b` to `wlan0`.